# How do you change a showcaseview circle radius?

Tags: android, showcaseview

I use the master code from git repo of the showcaseview library.

Since am new to setting up this library, I am not sure how one can reduce the size of the circle indicator.

Some legacy code contained config options where you can set the radius, but i couldn't find a source which has customising the same in the master repo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can globally change the radius creating these 3 entries in the `app/src/main/res/values/dimens.xml` file

```
<dimen name="showcase_radius">94dp</dimen>
<dimen name="showcase_radius_inner">96dp</dimen>
<dimen name="showcase_radius_outer">128dp</dimen>

<dimen name="showcase_radius_material">94dp</dimen>
```

I'm showing the default values.

Comment: But these should be added in my app's dimens.xml or is it in the library's dimens.xml? I would not prefer to alter the library anytime.

Comment: I added them in the app's file.

Comment: Yes yes. I tried this just now. And worked like a charn! Thanks a lot

Comment: To elaborate why this works: Due to resource inheritance, the compiler will overwrite any identical values that are defined in lower-priority modules if they are defined in higher priority modules. As long as you assign the values you want using the exact same name the library author used, (as shown in the answer) the values in the library's `dimens.xml` file will be overridden with your own values when the app is built.

Answer (score 4):

You're right. The old version of ShowcaseView has this ability but the new version - which is in Maven - does not. I hope to add it back soon. Sorry!

Comment: Also if there is a possibility to make the circle as custom shapes it would be highly appreciated! Things like rectangle over an edittext could look better when compared to a circle.

Comment: @Alex Curran. I'm using your library in Samsung note 3 Android KitKat. Your circle looks fine before i'm rotate the phone. After i rotate, example to landscape, the circle is missing. and after i rotate back to portrait mode, the circle show again. in my manifest, i handled orientation changes. I need to redraw the circle or moving circle position (maybe by pixel or something). Your library works fine in tablet 7+ inch. I don't know is it bug or something. How i can achieve this? Thanks